# Undefined symbol: _ZTI14QWSInputMethod

Tags: qt, embedded

I have cross-compiled a QT project in ubuntu12.04 using qmake version 4.8.4 and arm-none-linux-guneabi-4.4.3.In the project ,it also used the libsyszuxpinyin.so library.But when I run it On the arm board ,it run error with this problem.

So,I want to ask anyone just have encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set library path for QT libraries...?

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.4-sh4/lib: ....
```

Comment: There is something in this problem I can't understand. Just in an scenario: with a different library version in linking phase and running phase. In other case, undefined symbol should have been spotted in linking phase.

Comment: Yes, I made a qt_lib.img and grub it on the libpath,it then works

Comment: +1 It was possible that he linked against a different library than what was transferred to the host, but you were right.